# Change Primary Key Master Details Tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have Master Details Tables

MasterTBL

```
ID   Name  Age
12   name1  15
544  name2  15
2544 name3  15
```

DetailsTBL

```
ID session MasterID
1  Test    12
2  Test2   12
3  test3   544
4  test4   2544
5  test5   12
6  test6   544
```

Is it possible to change the ID of the master table and details table without data conflict 
to be like :

MasterTBL

```
ID   Name  Age
1    name1  15
2    name2  15
3    name3  15
```

DetailsTBL

```
ID session MasterID
1  Test    1
2  Test2   1
3  test3   2
4  test4   3
5  test5   1
6  test6   2
```

I used this function to do it in the master

```
row_number() over (order by id)
```

but what should I do to update the details

Comment: Why it is necessary to change the values of surrogate key. It is meaningless data, just an identifier of cortege.

Comment: Because my ID column in Master is INT not identity and I got numbers like 22569854487884 in my table so I need to make the numbers like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: How do you populate the table `MasterTBL`?

Comment: Why do you need to make it 1,2,3,4,5? Do you use that column in your `WHERE` clause in any query? It is not even going to be sorted on that order. Also int datatype cannot hold 22569854487884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (TempID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ID INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp (ID)
SELECT ID FROM MasterTBL
SET @Total = @@ROWCOUNT

DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @ID INT

WHILE @Count <= @Total
BEGIN

    SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM @Temp WHERE TempID = @Count)

    -- Update Details Table
    UPDATE DetailsTBL SET MasterID = @Count WHERE MasterID = @ID

    -- Update Master Table
    UPDATE MasterTBL SET ID = @Count WHERE ID = @ID

    SET @Count = @Count + 1
END
```

First need to update Details table, then Master table.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, do the following:

Add another column in your MasterTBL table to hold the values for your current ID and name it something meaningful e.g. OldID. Copy across the current ID values to this column, then you can update your ID field with the row_number function mentioned.

```
ID   Name  Age OldID
1   name1  15 12
2  name2  15 544
3 name3  15 2544
```

Then all you have to do, is join the DetailsTBL to the MasterTBL using the OldID column to get the new ID value to update the DetailsTBL table.